# Configuring App Engine path for PyDev on Mac

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

I've just installed Eclipse and the Pydev plug-in on my Mac (OS X 10.6.6) and I'm having trouble using the Google App Engine project 'template'. I'm really stuck here so your help would be really appreciated.

I can get as far as adding a New Project > Pydev > Pydev Google App Engine Project and setup the project name, directory and type etc no problem.

It then asks for the Google App Engine directory "Select the Google App Engine root directory (dir containing dev_appserver.py, appcfg.py, lib etc" but I can't find these files anywhere. I have of course already installed the Google App Engine SDK.

I did find a post that says I should specify the following path:

```
"/Applications/**GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app**/Contents/Resources/ 
GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/"
```

Notice this path includes a .app file (!?). I tried to navigate this structure and I can find the GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app file but can't navigate into it. I even tried pasting the path into the dialog directly... no luck.

What am I doing wrong? Help!

Yours, Confoosed.

Comment: To navigate into GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app (or any OSX for that matter) in Finder, right click the app and select "Show Package Contents".

Comment: Just dropping the asterisks and quotes from that path ought to do it. That is where `dev_appserver.py`, etc. live. It's frustrating that dialog gives you a Browse button, but of course on Mac you can't (easily) open a .app bundle, nor should you be asked to.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Put `/usr/local/google_appengine` as the path to ${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE} and Eclipse will resolve that symlink to `/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine`.

You should be able to see the /usr folder under Eclipse, which you normally won't see under Finder.

Comment: Annoyingly, since upgrading GAE I now get a new error: Did not find: /usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django - any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: That's because Google now has 2 versions of Django in the SDK now. django_0_96 and django_1_2. I think the latest PyDev fixed that. If not, you can make a symlink to point to either directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I was stuck for days. I simply searched for the dev_appserver.py file in the Finder and inserted that dir. Mine was just under the folder I initially pointed it toward on my Desktop and I was wasting time looking in the App folder. I hope that helps, even though its so simple to just search your whole dir sys for the file.

I had downloaded this  AppEngine SDK for Python on Mac OS X and it seemed like it was just the SDK without the dir that we need for the lib.

Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and run the [Google App Engine SDK for Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html) (the [AppEngine SDK for Python on Mac OS X](http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/GoogleAppEngineLauncher-1.4.1.dmg) may be found at that link), and you need to run the installer program. It will install the dev_appserver binary in `/usr/local/bin/`. You shouldn't try running the bundled code; one of the reasons why it is necessary to run in the installer and have it install the code in `/usr/local/bin/`, is that the installer will also periodically update those files which it has installed; if you run them directly from within the bundle, then you risk running out-of-date versions of those files.