# Using GoogleAppEngine with Python in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine

A while back I asked this question "[Using Google App Engine template from PyDev in Eclipse on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911823/using-google-app-engine-template-from-pydev-in-eclipse-on-mac)" and got a response. I've come back to this endeavour and find I now get a different error when trying to create a project:

Invalid Google App Engine directory. Did not find: /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django

Sure enough, I browsed around and can see:

{snip}/google_appengine/lib/django_0_96
and
{snip}/google_appengine/lib/django_1_2

but no

{snip}/google_appengine/lib/django

What's a kid to do?

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I feel like some kind of hardcore Mac expert.

I created a symlink like so:

ln -s "/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django_1_2/" "/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django"

And all seems well. Should I expect ill effects from this fix/hack?

Comment: This should be fine, but if you are actually using Django in your project be sure to specify which one using the `use_library` function. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django