# how to configure app engine sdk for php in eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I am setting up Google App Engine in my mac mini (Yosemite 10.10.1). I have installed following to set it up.

- Eclipse LUNA
- Google App Engine Launcher. It automatically installed App Engine SDK at /usr/local/google_appengine directory.
- Google plugin for Eclipse 4.4 (LUNA) as said [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse#Installing_the_Google_Plugin_for_Eclipse).

It shows error like "Failed to initialize App Engine SDK..."

[image: App Engine SDK installed]

[image]

What should I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on OS X Yosemite for PyDev Eclipse. After I read [the Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcpathvars.htm) and [some stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911823/configuring-app-engine-path-for-pydev-on-mac), I solved the problem.

1. Open File > Properties > Resource > Linked Resources on Eclipse
2. Define `GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE` as /usr/local/google_appengine.